`xdvipdfmx:fatal: Unrecognized paper format` after upgrading to TeXLive 2024
Can anyone tell me where to look to start diving into this situation? I upgraded my TeXLive and noticed that it's getting a big update (TeXLive 2024) and suddenly everything stops compiling. The log file currently keeps throwing this line.
xdvipdfmx:fatal: Unrecognized paper format: # Simply write the paper name. See man 1 paper and "paper --no-size --all" for possible values

I don't understand why it tells me to consult paper. The paper listed there is just A4 while as far as I know LaTeX uses a4paper. I begin to think that bad xdvipdfmx config is the culprit but I don't know how to do it. I'm using latexmk.
The MWE is literally just this.
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Edit this.
\end{document}

In the past, everything worked as intended.
===EDIT
I ran the document using xelatex and this is the result.
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999996 (TeX Live 2024/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test2.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def)
No file test2.aux.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd) [1] (./test2.aux)
xdvipdfmx:fatal: Unrecognized paper format: # Simply write the paper name. See man 1 paper and "paper --no-size --all" for possible values
 )
Error 256 (driver return code) generating output;
file test2.pdf may not be valid.
Transcript written on test2.log.

===Solution, but need research
The problem fixed after I eliminated the locale problem that perl keeps throwing at me. KDE overrides your locale and I set mine badly after KDE's locale settings have en_ID.UTF-8 but locale.gen doesn't (which proves no matter how many times you locale-gen your system, it doesn't work).

It would be useful to get the actual log file of your compilation of this particular MWE. Additionally it will be useful to kno0w which OS you are using?

try to compile simply with xelatex and not with latexmk. does that fail too?

Hey all. Thanks. I added the logfile after using only xelatex.

Correction: not the logfile, I mean the output of xelatex test2.tex.
The logfile itself is 76 lines long. Where should I put it?

The problem fixed, but any helps to know the exact reasons is still appreciated.

no matter how many times you locale-gen your system, it doesn't work: sorry, but it does work. Possibly it doesn't do what you think, though. locale-gen generates locales. The ones you generate are then available. It doesn't set anything. So if you've been thinking locale-gen would set your locale then, no, it won't ever do that and it isn't meant to. You need to set your locale in /etc/locale.conf. You also need to uncomment the locales you want in /etc/locale.gen and use locale-gen to generate them. And, yes, tell KDE, too. What does localectl; localectl list-locales return?

What does tlmgr paper give? [This might not work since you're using non-vanilla TeX Live, but it should return something even if it just tells you to run another distro-modified command.] If you are using A4 rather than letter, it should return a4 for a list of formats. E.g. the first two lines on my system are Current context paper size (from ): A4 Current dvipdfmx paper size (from /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/dvipdfmx/dvipdfmx.cfg): a4. It should NOT be a4paper. That's an option you use in your document. This is a TeX Live default.

@cfr Thanks. I screwed up some of my settings when I first installed the machine (I was (and still am) learning back then) and the locale setting is one of the things I have to deal with constantly. The localects; localectl list-locales now returns System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8     VC Keymap: (unset)             X11 Layout: (unset)          C.UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8 id_ID.UTF-8 What does it mean?

The second bit tells you which locales are available i.e. which ones you've generated. I don't know what id_ID.UTF-8 is - is that a language you recognise? C.UTF-8 is standard unicode - you definitely want that. en_US.UTF-8 is US English unicdoe - you definitely want that. What you want beyond those two depends on which languages you use. For example, I have C.UTF-8, cy_GB.UTF-8, en_GB.UTF-8 and en_US.UTF-8 because I want an additional language and an additional variety of English.

The first bit tells you what you're actually using. LANG=en_US.UTF-8 is fine if US English is your preferred language. I also have LANGUAGE set, but this may not matter if US English is your LANG. VC Keymap is the keyboard mapping used in the virtual console (i.e. not in X or Wayland). You haven't set it, so your system is probably guessing. Similarly for your X11 keyboard layout. (Are you even using X11? KDE now defaults to Wayland.) You should probably have LC_COLLATE=C showing up, though. If you know you messed this bit up, just go back to that bit of the wiki and work through it.

Ooh so that's what they meant. Thank you, it's more clearer now @cfr. The wiki is obv helpful but when things feel too muddy for me sometimes.

@Andre Yes. It sometimes is hard to find a starting point in the wiki. It can feel as if every page assumes you know a bunch of stuff which is explained somewhere else which assumes you know .... ;)

Here i put a solution under my condition:
Environment

OS:ArchLinux (5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2)
TeXLive:2024

bug
when compile the mwe given above, xetex throw an error message about paper settings like the above as well.
i then try command
tlmgr paper

throw the log
> tlmgr paper
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "en_US"
    are supported and installed on your system.

solution
then i try to set the varible LANGUAGE, LC_ALL, etc. in my default shell zsh (i.e., in file ~/.zshrc). i add the following code to this file:
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8

then i run tlmgr paper, the output:
> tlmgr paper
Current context paper size (from ): A4
Current dvipdfmx paper size (from /etc/texmf/dvipdfmx/dvipdfmx.cfg): a4
Current dvips paper size (from /etc/texmf/dvips/config/config.ps): a4
Current pdftex paper size (from /etc/texmf/tex/generic/tex-ini-files/pdftexconfig.tex): a4
Current psutils paper size (from /usr/share/texmf-dist/psutils/paper.cfg): a4
Current xdvi paper size (from /etc/texmf/xdvi/XDvi): a4

then everything works right, The problem fixed
